# одновременное выполнение двух классов - Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, классы

Это клиентская программа для анонимного сетевого чата.

Программа состоит из main и еще 4х классов

- Start посылает post запрос возвращает ID диентификатор чата
- Get   посылает post  запрос на ID, и возвращает сообщение написанное
  собеседником
- Send просит ввести сообщение с клавиатуры и посылает post запрос на
  ID чата
- Stop посылает post на ID о приостановке чата

мне нужно сделать так, что бы класс Get запускался через каждые 5 секунд, а Send работал независимо от него, понажатию кнопки enter

Как этого можно добиться?

```js
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Start Start1 = new Start();
    Get Get1 = new Get();
    Send Send1 = new Send();
    Stop Stop1 = new Stop();

    String userID = "000";
    String getString = "000";
    String Flag = "000";
    String Send = "000";

    try {
      userID = Start1.getid("trash");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } //Start


    int i = 1;
    while (i == 1) {

      try {
        getString = Get1.getter(userID);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } //get message
      System.out.println(getString);


      try {
        Send = Send1.sendstring(userID);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } //Send message

    }

    try {
      Flag = Stop1.disconnect(userID);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } //Stop

  }
}
```

Comment: О multithreading не слышали, а о timer?

Answer (score 3):

Не буду распространятся на тему Server Push..

чтобы запустить код в отдельном потоке нужно его сначала:

```
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    void run() {
       // your code here //
    }
};
```

а потом

```
Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.start();
```

или

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCacheedThreadPool();
executor.execute(task);
```

а для периодического выполнения :

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {

    }
}

int delay = 1000;
int repeat = 5000;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, delay, repeat);
```

как то так